# Rotated div disappears when scrolled under a fixed element

Tags: firefox, html, rotation

I'm working on a site, where we have a fixed menu on the top of the screen. And some rotated elements on the screen. Now when a user scrolls and let the rotated elements come beneat the fixed element they disapear in firefox on a small screen resolution. Below is a piece of test code that works the same and has the same problem:

```
<body style="height:800px;">
<div style="width:300px; height:50px; background:#aaa; position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; z-index:2;"></div>

<div style="position:absolute; height:1px; width:72.8804px; top: 118.3px; left: 108.843px; transform: rotate(-1.10069deg); background:#000;"></div></body>
```

Comment: don't use inline styles. So what's the question?

Comment: that was just a quick example, that reproduces the problem

Comment: The question is, when I scroll the page(make the browser window a bit smaller) in firefox so that the second div is under the first div and then you scroll back the second div doesn't show up. Now my question is how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

you can start with adding vendor prefixes:

```
transform: rotate(-1.10069deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(-1.10069deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-1.10069deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-1.10069deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(-1.10069deg);
```

Additionally, if you are using **z-index**, make sure that the elements that you want to be **above have higher value** than the elements that are below

Comment: The vendor prefix didn't help and the vendor prefixes are in the end product, but wheren't needed to show the problem.